# Python MySQLdb: creating database and filling table

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have written a small script to create a `MySQL` database, create a table (previously erase it if already exists), and insert many entries. When I execute my script, it works creating the database and table, but does not write any entry to the table:

```
from warnings import filterwarnings
import MySQLdb as db


filterwarnings('ignore', category = db.Warning)
try:
    db_name = 'chom'
    con = db.connect(user='user', passwd='pass')
    cur = con.cursor()

    # Create new database
    cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' + db_name + ';')

    # Create PARAMETERS table
    cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + db_name + '.PARAMETERS;')
    query = ('CREATE TABLE ' + db_name + '.PARAMETERS ('
      'idPARAMETERS INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, '
      'Param_name VARCHAR(30) NULL DEFAULT NULL, '
      'Param_value VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL, '
      'Timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP '
      'ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '
      'User_id VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL, '
      'PRIMARY KEY (idPARAMETERS) );'
    )
    cur.execute(query)

    # Insert entries
    parameters = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3',
        'param4']

    for i, param_name in enumerate(parameters, start=1):
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO ' + db_name + '.PARAMETERS '
            '(idPARAMETERS, Param_name, Param_value, User_id) '
            'VALUES (' + str(i) + ', %s, %s, %s);',
            (param_name, '', 'user2@localhost'))

    cur.close()
    con.commit()
except Exception, e:
    print 'Error. Last query: ' + str(cur._last_executed)
    print e
print 'DB installation script finished'
```

I can't see where the problem is. Any idea?

Comment: Anyway, I've executed the script as you've posted - it works for me and I see the records being inserted into `PARAMETERS` table. Are you sure you are checking the same database and table you are inserting into?

Comment: @alecxe You are right: it does work. I should not rely on the mysql-workbench software. Please answer saying that mysql-workbench is a piece of crap and I will accept your answer for yoru help

Comment: ha, I use MySQL Workbench on Linux, run your script and everything works fines. Wonder how to reproduce your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code worked correctly, it was mysql-workbench fault, which was not showing the correct database content (while mysql console client did).